# Question about connector, or how to connect

Tags: resistors, connector

I bought force sensing resistors and they have a flat connector at the end.
I tried to connect them to jumper cables but the fit isn't good.
https://www.interlinkelectronics.com/fsr-400

On the image labeled connector options I have the bottom one the one they call solder tabs. Does that mean you can solder on these?
Looking at the user guide it says:

> Do not solder directly to the exposed silver traces. With flexible
>   substrates, the solder joint will not hold and the substrate can
>   easily melt and distort during the soldering. Use Interlink
>   Electronics’ standard connection techniques, such as solderable tabs,
>   housed female contacts, Z-axis conductive tapes, or ZIF (zero
>   insertion force) style connectors.

I have no previous experience of any of those techniques (I think), Googling on them gives me some clues but not enough to say "That's what I'm going to do!".
So what is a good method to get a wire on these resistors?

Comment: **On the image labeled connector options I have the bottom one the one they call solder tabs** from question. See the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can solder onto the solder tabs.

The warning is saying not to solder directly onto the traces on the flexi-circuit.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was hoping for